# Query post category & remove any post id

Tags: posts, categories, query, query-posts

I have category_id=3 and have 10 post in category_id=3 with post_id= 1=>10

How to show list post category_id=3 with no post_id=1,3,5 value as

```
query_posts('cat=3& -p=1,3,5 &showposts=30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to omit posts 1,3,5 from category 3 on your blog, you can use the following code

```
$query = new WP_Query( array('cat' => 3, 'post_type' => 'post', 'post__not_in' => array(1,3,5) ) );
```

The query results will not show posts with ids 1,3,5 of category 3.

Answer (score -1):

You have placed minus sign before the parameter. This only work for inclusion of post.

For exclusion you have to use like this

```
query_posts(array('posts_per_page' => 10, 'post__not_in' => array(1,3,5)));
```

Check this in Wordpress [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Passing_variables_to_query_posts)